# How to use @Builder from lombok to build an entity when it needs another entity?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, testing

i was trying to build an entity of "Pessoa" for my backend test class, but it requires a "Cidade" type of property, and when i try to pass a new Cidade or instantiate a builder of Cidade to create a new valid one, i get the errors related to sql:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_PESSOA_CIDADE_ID: PUBLIC.PESSOA FOREIGN KEY(CIDADE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CIDADE(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
> insert into pessoa (apelido, cidade_id, cpf, hobbie, nome, time_coracao) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-200]

https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html

I already know that the error with code 23506 is thrown when trying to insert or update a row that would violate a referential constraint, because the referenced row does not exist.

But what I don't know is what to do to solve it, can someone help?

I have tried putting not yet existing Ids to create a new Cidade, but it didn't work. I have spent already more than 2 hours on this error.

Test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Log4j2
class PessoaRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Test
        void save_whenSuccessful(){
            Pessoa pessoa2BSalva = PessoaCreator.criarPessoa2BSalva();
            Pessoa pessoaSalva = this.pessoaRepository.save(pessoa2BSalva);
            Assertions.assertThat(pessoaSalva).isNotNull();
            Assertions.assertThat(pessoaSalva.getId()).isNotNull();
    }
```

Pessoa2BSalva method:

```
public static Pessoa criarPessoa2BSalva(){
        return Pessoa.builder()
                .nome("Roger")
                .cpf("54027892300")
                .apelido("Rogerinho")
                .timeCoracao("Flamengo")
                .hobbie("Futebol")
                .cidade(CidadeCreator.criarCidadeValida())
                .build();
    }
```

CriarCidadeValida method:

```
public static Cidade criarCidadeValida(){
        return Cidade.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .nome("Formiga")
                .estado("MG")
                .qtdHabitantes(75000).build();
    }
```

Any type of help is apreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, just provided some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I was not inserting a already existing Cidade, so what I did was change the @Test class to save a Cidade and assign to the Pessoa i was trying to save.

And after more than 2 hours of research I found my solution on [Spring boot : Referential integrity constraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973463/spring-boot-referential-integrity-constraint-violation) , at @Cristian Colorado answer

Here's my test class:

```
@Test
    void save_whenSuccessful(){
        Pessoa pessoa2BSalva = PessoaCreator.criarPessoa2BSalva();
        Cidade cidade2BSalva = CidadeCreator.criarCidade2BSalva();
        Cidade cidadeSalva = this.cidadeRepository.save(cidade2BSalva);
        pessoa2BSalva.setCidade(cidadeSalva);
        Pessoa pessoaSalva = this.pessoaRepository.save(pessoa2BSalva);
        Assertions.assertThat(pessoaSalva).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(pessoaSalva.getId()).isNotNull();
    }
```